# Error al tratar de implementar dagger hilt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy tratando de implementar dagger hilt en un proyecto nuevo desde cero, el proyecto es en view tradicionales xml por ser un requisito, al momento de implementar todo funciona bien pero al crear los modulos donde van a estar mis provide android studio deja de compilar y genera un error

> error: [Hilt]
> Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0 at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
> at
> dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)

La verdad no entiendo por que me genera ese error el proyecto es nuevo recien creado con las ultimas versiones de kotlin.
Aqui dejo mi codigo

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
}
```

Por alguna razon al agregar el @Modlue deja de funcionar sin mas, alguien podria indicarme el por que?
El @AndroidEntryPoint y el @HiltAndroidApp estan correctamente en sus respectivas clases

Comment: Hola. El mensaje de error es bastante claro *`Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0:`*. Hay un problema con tu versión de Kotlin. Agrega a la pregunta las implementaciones de Hilt que estás agregando en el archivo `build.gradle`, así como la configuración de Kotlin que tienes. Te recomendaría que si no lo has hecho, sigas paso por paso las [instrucciones para agregar Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=es-419), si ya lo hiciste, compara de nuevo, paso por paso que todo está correcto y en el `build.gradle` correcto.